# Call method in html input text with parameters + razor MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am assigning value of property to html input test box like below in my razor view (list.cshtml)

```
string  cap = item.GetValForProp<string>("Caption");

input type="text" name="Caption" class="txt" value="@cap"
```

This works fine.

However if I want to write it something like below:

```
input type="text" name="Caption" class="txt" value="@item.GetValForProp<string>("Caption")"
```

It is giving compilation error not recognizing "Caption" parameter. If I give single quotes, it is not considering that as parameter, giving exception that invalid arguments.

How can I correct this?

Block of code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

     cap = item.GetValForProp<string>("Caption");
     nameinuse = item.GetValForProp<string>("NameInUse");
     desc = item.GetValForProp<string>("Description");

    <tr>
        <td class="txt">
            <input type="text" name="Caption" class="txt" value="@cap"/>
            <input type="text" name="Caption" class="txt" value="@nameinuse"/>
            <input type="text" name="Caption" class="txt" value="@desc"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Are you using `IENumerable<>` model?

Comment: Yes my model is - @model IEnumerable<Organization>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using TextBox as below

```
@Html.TextBox("Caption", item.GetValForProp<string>("Caption"), new { @class = "txt" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping in parenthesis works - notice the @**(**  **)**:

```
<input type="text" name="Caption" class="txt" value="@(item.GetValForProp<string>("Caption"))">
```